# Inheritance in Java .. Why it Doesn't Print "5" in this code?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

Why is the output just `"AB8"`, and why is the `"5"` not printed ??!!

There are two classes. One of them extends from the Other.
When I create an Object from the subclass, it gives me this output `"AB8"`,
and I thought first it would be `"A5B8"`. So I would Understanding Why ?!

```
public class A {
    public A(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    public A(int i){
        this();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}



public class B extends A{
    public B(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
    public B(int i){
        this();
        System.out.println(i+3);
    }
}



public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it?  You would only print 5 in the A constructor with 1 argument, which never gets called.

Comment: If u r using any IDE like eclipse then in `new B(5);` put a debug point and do the debugging.It will clear ur confusion.

Answer (score 1):

-Parent constructors are called

In this case, A() is called, which prints out "A".

-Child constructor is called

In this case, B(int) is called, which prints out "B" from the call to this()
Then 5 + 3 is printed, which is 8.

It really helps to walk through the code, line by line OP...

Answer (score 1):

In B's constructor `B(int i)`, you call `this()`, which is the parameterless constructor of B. This will implicitly call the parameterless constructor of A, but it will never call `A(int i)`.

It is good practice to explicitly call A's constructor using the `super` keyword. The control flow becomes clearer.

```
public class A {
    public A(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    public A(int i){
        this(); // call the parameterless constructor of A
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    public B(){
        super(); // call the parameterless constructor of A
        System.out.println("B");
    }
    public B(int i){
        this(); // call the parameterless constructor of B
        System.out.println(i+3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new B(5);`, the flow is: `new A()` (because A is B's superclass), `new B()` (because you called `this()`) and finally `System.out.println(i+3);`